# How to get my raspberry pi to recognize my Ext4 formatted HDD

Tags: windows, mount, hard-drive, ext4

I'm trying to get my raspberry pi to function as a media center. Pretty much everything is working fine, but I can't seem to get it to recognize my ext4 formatted 1TB HDD. Whenever I go to Video/Choose files/Browse it isn't there. I need this drive to either play files locally or install the NetfliXBMC (and other) Add-On(s).

However, I would like to know a way to get it to recognize the drive without using the command line, as I am currently stuck to using Windows as my OS. For example, can I connect it to my Windows laptop and do some command line-esque things that way?

Comment: SSH into your RPi and do a `lsusb`. Please add the output to your question. Not sure if this question is on topic here.

Comment: If you are connecting a external hard drive to the Pi, you probably need to a use a externally powered USB hub as the Pi probably does not have enough power to spin up the hard drive. Could you please add the output of `dmesg | tail -50` [to your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/636624/edit)?

Comment: Of course! I'll look into the externally powered USB hub. I'm 99% sure that that's it. That was pretty dumb.... I'll comment again if I've tried this.. PS I can't SSH into the RPi unfortunately :( I'll need to know my RPi IP first and to do this I'll need to be able to read the micro SD, and of course the microSD reader in my laptop is broken... Yeah, I know...

Comment: @Wilf I have run RPis with external USB hubs without power, no problem. Running an external HDD without power won't work though.

Comment: Luc: you could do a scan of the network using nmap (available for Windows). The command `nmap -sP [network range]` will happily tell you where your Raspberry Pi is located. Then use something like PuTTY to ssh into your RPi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are stuck with Windows as your OS. Does this mean you cannot boot from a Live CD? If you could boot from a GNU/Linux Live CD (such as Ubuntu), you could then check if the USB is formatted correctly (or re-format using gparted) *without* affecting the contents of your computer's hard drive.

HTH.

Comment: The [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) is also a option

Comment: Yes I could do this (just can't switch OS's in the middle of finishing my BSc). I'll look into this ASAP.

Comment: @Luc Evertzen Yes, definitely do not meddle with your computer's configuration at this time. Also do keep backups current (been there, done that ;-) ). Good luck with the Batchelor.